# Embed video on a asp.net-mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video

I will be embedding a video to my asp.net mvc website. 
A video on the homepage which will help people to better understand the website.
I have never done this. Can anyone tell me whats the best way of doing it.
Flash or silverlight??

Comment: There sure are a lot of Stus in this question...

Answer (score 2):

I've used JW FLV Media Player.  I was pretty happy with it, and it's easy to use.  Flash-based.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to go with Flash and to achieve what you're looking for, utilize [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). It's really quite simple to use and has a bunch of options that will be useful when you get more used to using video.

Answer (score 0):

I have had pretty good success using silverlight with the [Silverlight 2 Video Player](http://www.codeplex.com/sl2videoplayer) as an example.  However, it depends on what your requirements are.

Pros to Silverlight:

- Performs Video Streaming very well
- Easier to develop/customize if you are a .NET developer
- Works on a variety of browser and platforms

Cons to Silverlight:

- Does not support every video media type (the example above only plays .WMV files, Silverlight in general supports .WMV and .MP4)
- Is not installed on as many client machines (less penetration)
- Is not as well known (users may be reluctant to install it compared to Flash)
- Is not as popular so there are less solutions/resources out there

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104270/flash-vs-silverlight) is another discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with flash for only one reason: the 99% (or whatever it is today) installed base.

Then go with swfobject or JW FLV Media Player as suggested in the other answers.  There is also a jQuery plugin floating around somewhere that helps deal with flash video on a site.