# How do I embed a flash object in my MVC2 Application Home?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flash, asp.net-mvc-2, flashdevelop

I need to put a Flash Object in my website developed on MVC2 .NET, however the third party who made it just gave me an html with this code.HTML errors apart I don't know how to put it on ASP.NET. Can you help me?

```
      <table width="608" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#F4F4F4"> 
        <tr> 
          <td height="412"> 
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" id="runtime" width="608" height="412" align="middle"> 
              <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> 
              <param name="movie" value="runtime.swf" /> 
              <param name="menu" value="false" /> 
              <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
              <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> 
              <param name="FlashVars" value="Runtime_settingPath=modules/main/setting.xml&Runtime_isRemote=false&Runtime_init_module=module1&Runtime_init_scene=scene1.swf" /> 
              <EMBED src="runtime.swf" FlashVars="Runtime_settingPath=modules/main/setting.xml&Runtime_isRemote=false&Runtime_init_module=module1&Runtime_init_scene=scene1.swf"  quality=high bgcolor=#CCCCCC  WIDTH="608" HEIGHT="412" NAME="runtime" swLiveConnect="true" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> 
            </object> 
          </td> 
          </tr> 
      </table>
```

Comment: I solved my problem, probably not using any correct form, but as it was urgent I opted for the shortest way... Came with the idea of using iframes so I could use the entirely html the third party flash developers sent me...

Thanks all for your post though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Embed video on a asp.net-mvc website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561906/embed-video-on-a-asp-net-mvc-website) question and the answers. The SWF Object works very well.

I used the [JW FLV player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) together with this explanation: http://codevoyeur.com/Articles/15/ASP.NET-MVC-HtmlHelper-Extensions-for-the-JW-FLV-Media-Player.aspx in several asp.net mvc sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste that in an MVC View. Views can have plain old HTML code.

Comment: I did. It doesn't work. May be some of the tags might be wrong. However I'm not a flash expert. I could tell you that the HTML they sent me has 43 errors according to the HTML Validator.

Comment: I think my problem is with the routes for the FlashVar but I don't know how to manage those on MVC 2

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is any different than embed a flash object in a page. Any error you may be getting is definitely unrelated to it being in asp.net MVC.

> I did. It doesn't work. May be some of the tags might be wrong. However I'm not a flash expert. I could tell you that the HTML they sent me has 43 errors according to the HTML Validator.

We are not the ones to complain about it ;). Put it in the simplest html page, and send it back as a test case that it doesn't work.