# playing video in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

here i am working on a project in which a user can upload many videos and can view so now i want to develop something which played video file also on low bandwidth internet connection and i never did such as work before so i don't have any idea about so please suggest me some user tips and techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider using Silverlight or Flash. Currently those are the most commonly used solutions for your needs.

Comment: yes but if we are using flash player then we have to convert the video file to flash video and hows it will be , i don't know ...is there any way to convert a video directly to flash video ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SilverLight player ([article](http://ask.officelive.com/smallbusiness/wiki/articles/add-a-video-to-your-web-site-using-silverlight.aspx)) to stay with .net background but also can mix site with Flash (flash advantage: it's much more [widespread](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/03/Flash-Silverlight) compared to silverlight, though the [gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104270/flash-vs-silverlight) is getting closer)

[How to put video on site with Flash](http://www.sothinkmedia.com/guide/putvideo.htm)

Comment: yes dude but can you tell me hows can i convert a media file to flash using c#  ?

Comment: I suppose you should try some free (or nearly free) avi to flv converters  http://www.videozilla.net/, ImTOO FLV Converter, e.t.c that support console mode batch conversion. You can execute console to complete conversion task and programatically terminate task if it hangs for some reason or workstation is getting out of memory.

Comment: thank a lot to reply ,
is there any programmatic techniques from which can we convert the video files to flash without using these converters ?

Comment: take a look at http://www.dominion-web.com/applications/flvconverter/ (I suspect it's just exe call wrapper).  There is also similar discussion: http://techrepublic.com.com/5208-3513-0.html?forumID=101&threadID=244700

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick to .net platform try using Silverlight video players.. they have good support for streaming and buffering for various media types..

try this:
http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/

Regards.

Comment: thank dude, yes i am looking for that one but still i am searching for better one...

Comment: better one? wht else do u need? do u have some other requirements with playing video?