# Play Video in ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well, it's simple as that.

How can i play video (such as mp4) within my website.

I know that I am not writing much and I have a lot to explain, but it's as simple as that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [playing video in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234515/playing-video-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jw player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). open source.

Comment: any expline on how to use it? Thanks dude.

Comment: Well there are 3 ways of doing it. From newest to oldest they are JW Embedder, SWFObject and the Embed Tag. I would refer to the [Getting Started](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15991/getting-started) documentation. JW Embedder is the preferred way. If your video is on your site, easy peasy. If you have it up on a CDN, then read [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/17674/configuring-the-jw-player-for-your-cdn)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about website coding, but Directshow and DirectShow.net are relatively easy from a coding standpoint.